# ASP.Net Custom HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a custom `HttpModule` for a web application.  In the module I am writing session variables.  This works except on pages with an `Ajax ScriptManager`.  When the page loads I get the dreaded `'Sys' is undefined`.  This only happens on pages with `ScriptManager`.  To debug the problem I removed my `HttpModule` from the application and moved the code to the global.asax in the application.  Now this is the only event method I have in my global.asax:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    application.Session["aVariable"] = "some value";
}
```

Any page/master page that has a `ScriptManager` throws one or more `"'Sys' is undefined"`errors.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The app is in .NET 3.5.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem with this before. There are a lot of causes but this one fixed it for me...

Here is an extract from the post I wrote about it.

Finally after double checking absolutely everything I noticed that one of the handlers the web config was referencing did not have an extension mapping. This was the .axd extension. I added this in to IIS but the problem still occurred. Checking the handler mapping again I unchecked the 'Verify that the file exists' check box and retried the web page. This time it worked!

full post with screenshot @ http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2010/09/ajax-sys-in-undefined-and-ajax-client.html

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but the verify option is already checked.
I did notice that the only time I get this error is when I try to write a session variable in the "PreRequestHandlerExecute" event and the following tag is on the page:
`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>`

Found the solution.
Just had to add `"if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session != null)"`.

Thanks.